# Can't log out, shutdown or restart macOS Sierra since the update

Tags: preferences, macos, shutdown

Since I have updated the OS to Sierra, I'm facing several issue (one example: [Character Accent Menu doesn't appear anymore in macOS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254094/character-accent-menu-doesnt-appear-anymore-in-macos-sierra/254161?noredirect=1#comment316922_254161))

Another bothering issue that is, I just can't log out.
If I try to log out, shut down or restart the device, my applications are getting closed, the status and dock bars disappear, then... nothing. 
Just the desktop's background and my mouse. Can't do anything except moving the house, can't open Finder anymore, etc... 
The only way is to do a long press on the power button.

If I log as a guest user, this problem does not occur. So, like my keyboard's issue, it has something to do with some broken plist, preferences...

Anyway to trackdown what is causing that?

Comment: Did you do a clean install or did you do an in place update?  I have found that many of my clients who decided to do an in place update rather than a clean (wipe the system and start from scratch) have much more problems than the latter group.

Comment: In place update. Like the keyboard issue I had, something got broken during the update.

Comment: My recommendation is to redo the install but this time erase the drive prior to install (clean installation).  I assume you have a backup (time machine or other) already done prior to the update.