# Character Accent Menu doesn't appear anymore in macOS High Sierra

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, internationalization

Firstly, this is for **High** Sierra

I've already tried this step:

> [Character Accent Menu doesn't appear anymore in macOS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254094/character-accent-menu-doesnt-appear-anymore-in-macos-sierra/254161)

- Add a second language like French in Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Source
- When I type `defaults read -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` in a Terminal
  I got a `1`
- Go into Settings, Keyboard and make sure the Key Repeat slider is set to Slow and the Delay Until Repeat slider is set to Short.

Even if I restart the Accent Menu doesn't appear.

And this is my Mac:

> macOS High Sierra | version 10.13, MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Comment: Do you have any antivirus stuff installed, or 3rd party apps that are aimed at text handling?  Try setting up a new user account and see if you still have the problem when logged into that.

Comment: @TomGewecke oh your right, when i create a new account i got the accent menu, and after delete apps after apps i discover that was Filezilla... but it's only work in Notes actually

Comment: Hey I followed your steps and then restarted my computer. Everything worked perfectly afterwards

Comment: @florian-do If your issue was related to Filezilla and has been solved, please detail what you did to fix it in an answer below to help future people who may have this problem.

Comment: @timothymh hello, as i said in my previous comment, the accent menu is only showing on the 'notes' app and finaly it's not related to Filezilla

Comment: I am also having this issue after High Sierra update. When I type `defaults read -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` I got a `The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, ApplePressAndHoldEnabled) does not exist`

Comment: i have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) and just upgraded to Mac OS High Sierra. I downloaded commander One and uninstall it same day with great hardships - seemed it didn't want to get rid-off. Now i can't input any french accent. Have tried using another user account, and opened pages there - ideally the accent worked pretty good there. I don't know what to do? I am quite tempted to downgrade back to previous Sierra using the time machine way etc.... but I am not that adventurous, fearing i might get things worst for my mac.

Comment: @Jacksparrow Can you make french accent acute via the normal option key shortcut, option e followed by the base letter.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @TomGewecke said the only way I found to solve this bug was to create another user or to reinstall Mac OS High Sierra

Answer (score 0):

[MacPilot](https://www.koingosw.com/products/macpilot/) has a setting that allows you to enable the accent menu in:

Apps > System > Interface > Pressing and holding keys shows accent menu

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too when upgrading from macOS Monterey to Ventura. You can fix it using [Juliet Sychrava's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268386/98135), it worked for me:

> I've just got the answer to this from Apple. Go into Settings, Keyboard and make sure the Key Repeat slider is set to Slow and the Delay Until Repeat slider is set to Short. That fixes it. If the keyboard is working too fast, the menu won't appear.