# Displaying Accents on Touch Bar not working anymore

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

For some reason, a long press of a letter doesn't bring up the accented letters anymore on the Touch Bar (MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2018, US keyboard). It does bring up the accented character menu, so that you can chose by pressing a number.

I spent couple of hours on the phone with Apple Care folks trying to figure it out but still don't have a solution. I don't have Webroot or any such other program installed...what's really annoying is that I created a second test account, and there it works fine. Has anyone figured out a solution to this???

Edit: This is a different question b/c it's not an issue with Webroot or some other anti-virus software. I don't have those installed.

Also, I tried a PRAM and SMC reset and no help. It doesn't work in safe boot either - not on the main account at least.

Edit 2: Added image. This is what should be happening on the Touch Bar. But it doesn't.

[image]

Comment: Can you share how I can test this on my machine? Can you add a screenshot of what the Touch Bar looks like when it works properly?

Comment: Have you tried any of these suggestions? They aren't directly related to Touch Bar, but may be worth a try. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254094/character-accent-menu-doesnt-appear-anymore-in-macos-sierra

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I did try them. They don't help as they deal with the accented letter pop-up happening on screen...that works, but that's not supposed to be happening. Let me take a picture of the Touch Bar in the other user; I'll update the question then (if I can figure out how - asking on here is a bit new to me.)

Comment: P.S. Just realized you asked about testing this on your machine: if you have the touch bar, then holding a letter that may have accents, should have this pop up. The letter a is the easiest option to test this on.

Comment: I can try again later, but previously that didn’t happen for me -leads me to believe it requires some kind of configuration. Does it maybe require setting the language of the keyboard to something other than English?

Comment: Another idea, do you have “typing suggestions” turned on?

Comment: Yeah, I tried changing / adding keyboards, but it didn't do anything. On the guest user there is also only one keyboard input source (US Engl),  and it works fine. Same w/typing suggestions, but I'll go check it out again.

Comment: Typing suggestions didn't seem to help for me, couldn't get it to work.